# the admob ads is not Show in app android in the first run

Tags: android, webview, admob

I'm using Webview in an Android app. When I run the app, the admob is not show in the first run. If I run the app again, the admob shows. Why is this happening?

I do see an exception in my logs (below the code):

```
    public class WebViewClientDemoActivity extends Activity {

    WebView web;
    ProgressDialog  pd;
    Button button1;
    private AdView adView;
    private InterstitialAd interstitial;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

       interstitial = new InterstitialAd(WebViewClientDemoActivity.this);
        interstitial.setAdUnitId("XXXXXXXXXXXXXX");
        AdRequest adRequest2 = new AdRequest.Builder()
       .build();


        adView = (AdView)findViewById(R.id.adView);
        AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder()
        .build();

        adView.loadAd(adRequest);
       interstitial.loadAd(adRequest2);

       interstitial.setAdListener(new AdListener() {
            public void onAdLoaded() {
                displayInterstitial();
            }
        });

        button1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        button1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                web.loadUrl("XXXXXXXXXXXXXX");
                interstitial.show();
                }
        });

        if(isNetworkStatusAvialable (getApplicationContext())) {
            web = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview01);
            web.setWebViewClient(new myWebClient());
            web.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
            web.loadUrl("XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX");
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "لا يوجد اتصال بالانترنت !!!",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        }

    }



    public void displayInterstitial() {
            if (interstitial.isLoaded()) {
                interstitial.show();
            }
        }

    public class myWebClient extends WebViewClient
    {
        @Override
        public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
            super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);
            if (pd == null) {
                // in standard case YourActivity.this
                pd = new ProgressDialog(WebViewClientDemoActivity.this);
                pd.setMessage("انتظر لحظة...");
                pd.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
                pd.show();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {         
            view.loadUrl(url);
            return false;
            }

        @Override
        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
            super.onPageFinished(view, url);
             try{
                 if (pd.isShowing()) {
                     pd.dismiss();
                    pd = null;
                 }
                 }catch(Exception exception){
                     exception.printStackTrace();
                 }

             }


    }

    @Override
    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        if(event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN){
            switch(keyCode)
            {
            case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK:
                if(web.canGoBack()){
                    web.goBack();
                }else{
                    finish();
                }
                return true;
            }

        }
        return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
    }

    public void onPause() {
          adView.pause();
          super.onPause();
        }

        @Override
        public void onResume() {
          super.onResume();
          adView.resume();
        }

        @Override
        public void onDestroy() {
          adView.destroy();
          super.onDestroy();

        }

        public static boolean isNetworkStatusAvialable (Context context) {
            ConnectivityManager connectivityManager = (ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
            if (connectivityManager != null) 
            {
                NetworkInfo netInfos = connectivityManager.getActiveNetworkInfo();
                if(netInfos != null)
                if(netInfos.isConnected()) 
                    return true;
            }
            return false;
        }

}
```

Log Cat

```
10-27 19:37:01.806: V/WebViewChromiumFactoryProvider(1188): Binding Chromium to main looper Looper (main, tid 1) {5284e270}
10-27 19:37:01.806: I/LibraryLoader(1188): Expected native library version number "",actual native library version number ""
10-27 19:37:01.806: I/chromium(1188): [INFO:library_loader_hooks.cc(116)] Chromium logging enabled: level = 0, default verbosity = 0
10-27 19:37:01.870: I/BrowserStartupController(1188): Initializing chromium process, renderers=0
10-27 19:37:02.142: E/AudioManagerAndroid(1188): BLUETOOTH permission is missing!
10-27 19:37:02.566: D/libEGL(1188): loaded /system/lib/egl/libEGL_genymotion.so
10-27 19:37:02.566: D/(1188): HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0xb79670d0, tid 1188
10-27 19:37:02.574: D/libEGL(1188): loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv1_CM_genymotion.so
10-27 19:37:02.574: D/libEGL(1188): loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv2_genymotion.so
10-27 19:37:02.666: W/chromium(1188): [WARNING:mailbox_synchronizer.cc(36)] MailboxSync not supported due to missing EGL image/fence support
10-27 19:37:02.778: D/dalvikvm(1188): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 91K, 4% free 3805K/3960K, paused 2ms, total 2ms
10-27 19:37:02.782: I/dalvikvm-heap(1188): Grow heap (frag case) to 6.192MB for 2536932-byte allocation
10-27 19:37:02.786: D/dalvikvm(1188): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed <1K, 3% free 6282K/6440K, paused 2ms, total 2ms
10-27 19:37:03.078: W/chromium(1188): [WARNING:proxy_service.cc(890)] PAC support disabled because there is no system implementation
10-27 19:37:03.082: W/GooglePlayServicesUtil(1188): Google Play services is missing.
10-27 19:37:03.130: D/dalvikvm(1188): DexOpt: --- BEGIN 'ads-456905124.jar' (bootstrap=0) ---
10-27 19:37:03.138: W/GooglePlayServicesUtil(1188): Google Play services is missing.
10-27 19:37:03.142: I/Ads(1188): Starting ad request.
10-27 19:37:03.142: I/Ads(1188): Use AdRequest.Builder.addTestDevice("3A1ADC6C8879D79A9A6D537320830C10") to get test ads on this device.
10-27 19:37:03.146: W/GooglePlayServicesUtil(1188): Google Play services is missing.
10-27 19:37:03.146: I/Ads(1188): Starting ad request.
10-27 19:37:03.146: I/Ads(1188): Use AdRequest.Builder.addTestDevice("3A1ADC6C8879D79A9A6D537320830C10") to get test ads on this device.
10-27 19:37:03.250: D/dalvikvm(1188): DexOpt: --- END 'ads-456905124.jar' (success) ---
10-27 19:37:03.250: D/dalvikvm(1188): DEX prep '/data/data/com.hostwr.ibrahemfeqy/cache/ads-456905124.jar': unzip in 0ms, rewrite 117ms
10-27 19:37:03.498: W/EGL_genymotion(1188): eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
10-27 19:37:03.502: E/OpenGLRenderer(1188): Getting MAX_TEXTURE_SIZE from GradienCache
10-27 19:37:03.502: E/OpenGLRenderer(1188): MAX_TEXTURE_SIZE: 8192
10-27 19:37:03.506: E/OpenGLRenderer(1188): Getting MAX_TEXTURE_SIZE from Caches::initConstraints()
10-27 19:37:03.510: E/OpenGLRenderer(1188): MAX_TEXTURE_SIZE: 8192
10-27 19:37:03.510: D/OpenGLRenderer(1188): Enabling debug mode 0
10-27 19:37:03.514: W/AwContents(1188): nativeOnDraw failed; clearing to background color.
10-27 19:37:03.702: W/AwContents(1188): nativeOnDraw failed; clearing to background color.
10-27 19:37:04.582: W/AwContents(1188): nativeOnDraw failed; clearing to background color.
10-27 19:37:04.622: W/AwContents(1188): nativeOnDraw failed; clearing to background color.
10-27 19:37:04.638: W/AwContents(1188): nativeOnDraw failed; clearing to background color.
10-27 19:37:04.658: W/AwContents(1188): nativeOnDraw failed; clearing to background color.
10-27 19:37:04.678: W/AwContents(1188): nativeOnDraw failed; clearing to background color.
10-27 19:37:04.710: W/AwContents(1188): nativeOnDraw failed; clearing to background color.
10-27 19:37:04.734: W/AwContents(1188): nativeOnDraw failed; clearing to background color.
10-27 19:37:04.758: W/AwContents(1188): nativeOnDraw failed; clearing to background color.
10-27 19:37:04.782: W/AwContents(1188): nativeOnDraw failed; clearing to background color.
10-27 19:37:04.802: W/AwContents(1188): nativeOnDraw failed; clearing to background color.
10-27 19:37:04.822: W/AwContents(1188): nativeOnDraw failed; clearing to background color.
10-27 19:37:04.842: W/AwContents(1188): nativeOnDraw failed; clearing to background color.
10-27 19:37:04.862: W/AwContents(1188): nativeOnDraw failed; clearing to background color.
10-27 19:37:06.706: D/dalvikvm(1188): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 467K, 8% free 6639K/7168K, paused 4ms, total 4ms
10-27 19:37:06.706: I/dalvikvm-heap(1188): Grow heap (frag case) to 7.141MB for 629772-byte allocation
10-27 19:37:06.718: D/dalvikvm(1188): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed <1K, 7% free 7253K/7784K, paused 14ms, total 14ms
10-27 19:37:06.850: W/EGL_genymotion(1188): eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
10-27 19:37:07.330: I/chromium(1188): [INFO:async_pixel_transfer_manager_android.cc(60)] Async pixel transfers not supported
10-27 19:37:07.406: I/chromium(1188): [INFO:async_pixel_transfer_manager_android.cc(60)] Async pixel transfers not supported
10-27 19:37:07.670: E/eglCodecCommon(1188): **** ERROR unknown type 0x238e0a (glSizeof,73)
10-27 19:37:07.678: I/Choreographer(1188): Skipped 30 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
10-27 19:37:07.902: E/eglCodecCommon(1188): **** ERROR unknown type 0x238e0a (glSizeof,73)
10-27 19:37:07.986: W/EGL_genymotion(1188): eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
10-27 19:37:08.102: E/eglCodecCommon(1188): **** ERROR unknown type 0x238e0a (glSizeof,73)
10-27 19:37:08.358: E/eglCodecCommon(1188): **** ERROR unknown type 0x238e0a (glSizeof,73)
10-27 19:37:12.870: W/System.err(1188): java.lang.NullPointerException
10-27 19:37:12.870: W/System.err(1188):     at com.hostwr.ibrahemfeqy.WebViewClientDemoActivity$myWebClient.onPageFinished(WebViewClientDemoActivity.java:118)
10-27 19:37:12.870: W/System.err(1188):     at com.android.webview.chromium.WebViewContentsClientAdapter.onPageFinished(WebViewContentsClientAdapter.java:455)
10-27 19:37:12.870: W/System.err(1188):     at com.android.org.chromium.android_webview.AwContentsClient$AwWebContentsObserver.didFinishLoad(AwContentsClient.java:62)
10-27 19:37:12.870: W/System.err(1188):     at com.android.org.chromium.base.SystemMessageHandler.nativeDoRunLoopOnce(Native Method)
10-27 19:37:12.870: W/System.err(1188):     at com.android.org.chromium.base.SystemMessageHandler.handleMessage(SystemMessageHandler.java:24)
10-27 19:37:12.870: W/System.err(1188):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
10-27 19:37:12.870: W/System.err(1188):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
10-27 19:37:12.870: W/System.err(1188):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5001)
10-27 19:37:12.870: W/System.err(1188):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
10-27 19:37:12.870: W/System.err(1188):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
10-27 19:37:12.870: W/System.err(1188):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
10-27 19:37:12.870: W/System.err(1188):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
10-27 19:37:12.870: W/System.err(1188):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
10-27 19:37:13.318: E/eglCodecCommon(1188): **** ERROR unknown type 0x238e0a (glSizeof,73)
10-27 19:37:13.330: W/Ads(1188): There was a problem getting an ad response. ErrorCode: 0
10-27 19:37:13.342: W/Ads(1188): Failed to load ad: 0
10-27 19:37:13.342: W/Ads(1188): There was a problem getting an ad response. ErrorCode: 0
10-27 19:37:13.362: W/Ads(1188): Failed to load ad: 0
```

Answer (score 0):

You should'nt have displayInterstitial() inside onAdLoaded(). This is causing the outcome of Ad being shown only on the 2nd time you open your app. It may show Ad to your user in an unwanted way ( against what developer wants). Just use displayInterstitial() either after finishing level or user doing some action.

Comment: i stoped Interstitial ad code but ads banner not show

Comment: check that you haven't by mistake removed code related to banner ads. Because banner ads should display without requiring interstitials to be shown.

Answer (score 0):

If anyone is also currently experiencing the same issue. I thought, i should suggest you check your admob account and you may find that you need to fix your PIN so that your ads start showing.

Hope this helps someone.